# Image preview / thumb not showing in Drupal 8

Tags: image, media, drupal-8

I am facing a strange issue regarding image preview in Drupal 8. I tried will all the patches available in the net
-disable "itok"
-set permission 775 to sites/default/files/styles directory and subdirectory
-even changed the default file permission from 0664 to 0775
-disable Options in .htaccess file
None is working

The image below is a preview page by "focal point" module. You see the preview is not showing. But if i click on preview, the image is showing at the bottom. I checked in the corresponding folder all preview images are there. A sample url is like this:

`/sites/default/files/styles/facebook/public/assets/Q292ZXIyMDExLTA2LTIzIDE5OjE2OjI3.jpg`

Now if I go directly to that image in browser, its displaying correctly. And after that, if I refresh the focal point preview, now that image will display. But if I clear the varnish cache, everything will be as before.

In whole site, where there is image preview, after upload or any preview, its happening the same.

The system is based on Drupal 8.4.x
- Its in Acquia Hosting
- Its using Media Entity, Media Entity Image, Entity Browser, Crop modules etc

I am banging my head almost two days, no clue of this issue. If anyone can help, will be highly appreciated!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 days, I found the issue. Somebody added some debug code in settings.php at the top before "

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>

<?php
```